# Using WAMPSERVER and getting issue

Tags: mysql, wampserver

I am using WAMPSERVER for creating a database using MYSQL. I wrote a basic query for creating a database that is:

```
CREATE DATABASE mydb
```

Upon clicking the *go* button, I am getting the error:

```
#1044 - Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'mydb'
```

Please tell that what can I do in this case. Thanks a lot for giving me your important time.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this issue..

Open the  config.inc.php file in phpMyAdmin folder and change the username and password which you like to set. Just check following code.

```
/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'Enter-Username';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'Enter-Password';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPasswordRoot'] = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to authenticate with the mysql server, and then check you have the correct permissions to create databases with the authenticated user.

Comment: I didnt set any kind of authentication, I am using it as localhost

Comment: did you set up a root login for mysql when you installed wamp?

Comment: No, i did not set any type of root login and else. I searched for this online and everywhere people are asking for login and password and don't know from where to get it as I am asking for too.

Comment: @RiggsFolly phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 0):

The error code

```
#1044 - Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'mydb'
```

Suggests that you have not logged in using a userid.

All installations of MySQL comes with a default userid setup of 'root' ( no quotes )

So try logging in again and use:

```
username = root
password = (leave this blanks)
```

You should then see a screen with a `add password` link on it. Click that and give the root userid a password, for security.
**Dont forget that password.**

Now you will be properly logged in to mysql and will have the required privilages to do, well anything, as the root userid is the super user.